# Determine radio button not selected anymore

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a javascript function that change the style of a div (here a TR tag) when I select a radio button in form (called by onchange event).

```
function handleCheck(myRadio) {
    var vak = 'vak' + myRadio.name + 'x' + myRadio.value;
    var col = document.getElementById(vak);
    col.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
    col.style.color = "white"; 
}
```

However, often when you select option X another option is deselected while you can select only one value at the time in the same. This option is not triggered by the onchange event. Is there a way to determine that a radio button is not checked any more?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked and `if (element.checked)`.

Comment: I don't think I clearly understood your question, can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to clear previously assigned classes. Take a look at this example:

```
function handleCheck(myRadio) {
    clear(myRadio.className);
    var vak = 'vak' + myRadio.name + 'x' + myRadio.value;
    var col = document.getElementById(vak);
    col.className += ' selected'; 
}

function clear(className) {
    var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr.vak' + className);
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        tr[i].className = 'vak' + className;
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abh7guv5/

Comment: that's fine. Just bear in mind, that querySelectorAll is supported by the most, but not every browser. Here's more info: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: I know, IE8+, that's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, simply read `document.getElementById("myRadio").checked` - it will be true or false

Answer (score 0):

well, if I understand you correctly, you have a function that applies some styles whenever you check a radio button, but you also would like to remove styles from elements, that corresponds to already unchecked buttons. If yes, you can store your previous checked item in a variable, then you might want something like:

```
var previousElement = null;
function handleCheck(myRadio) {
   var vak = 'vak' + myRadio.name + 'x' + myRadio.value;
   var col = document.getElementById(vak);
   col.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
   col.style.color = "white";

   if(previousElement!==null&&previousElement!==col){
       previousElement.style.color = ""; // or whatever you want
   }
   previousElement = col;
}
```